# Rotate marker annotations

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot, plot-annotations

I'd like to rotate text / labels for each `(x,y)` scatterplot points.

Here's my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn sns 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"one": [1,2,3,5,6,7,8],
                   "two": [3,6,4,3,8,2,5],
                   "label":['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']})

ax = sns.scatterplot(x='one', y='two', data = df1)

for line in range(0,df1.shape[0]):
    ax.text(df1.one[line]+0.04, 
            df1.two[line], 
            df1.label[line], horizontalalignment='left', 
            size='medium', color='black', weight='semibold')
```

[image]

I'd like to rotate labels to 45, so that they're visible / clear.

Comment: pass `rotation='45'` in `ax.text()` method inside your for loop

Comment: rotation=45 (no quotes)

Comment: Have you tried it by passing rotation parameter in `ax.text()`?.....yes it is accepted either you pass value as an integer or as a string it won't affect the result

Answer (score 3):

use this code for rotate the label on graph

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"one": [1,2,3,5,6,7,8],
                   "two": [3,6,4,3,8,2,5],
                   "label":['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']})
ax=sns.scatterplot(x='one', y='two', data = df1)

a=pd.concat({"x":df1["one"],"y":df1["two"],"lab":df1["label"]},axis=1)
for i ,point in a.iterrows():
    ax.text(point['x'],point['y'],str(point['lab'])).set_rotation(45)
```

[image: to rotate the label in graph]

Comment: `ax.text(point['x'],point['y'], str(point['lab']), rotation=45)`

Answer (score 1):

The following would do it:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
p1 = sns.scatterplot(x='one', y='two', data=df1, legend=False)  

for i in range(0,df1.shape[0]):
    p1.text(df1.one[i]+0.04, df1.two[i], 
    df1.label[i], horizontalalignment='left', 
    size='medium', color='black', weight='semibold')

plt.title('Example Plot')
plt.xlabel('One')
plt.ylabel('Two')
```

[image]